# How to retrieve a large file from PHAsset and upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, nsdata, dropbox-api

I have a large file stored on my iPhone (a 8 minutes video which weighs 550 Mo).
When I tried to retrieve it from PHAsset to NSData :

```
[[PHCachingImageManager alloc]requestAVAssetForVideo:lastAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset* asset, AVAudioMix* audioMix, NSDictionary* info)
 {
     NSString *tmp = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
     AVURLAsset* _asset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
     data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_asset.URL];
     [data writeToFile:tmp atomically:YES];
     [dbRestClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:folderToSave withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmp];
}];
```

I receive this error message when I reach the line `data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_asset.URL];`

This is my console log :

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=557903872) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So I think it's because the file is too large to be stored in an NSData.

So I don't have any ideas of what can I do to retrieve the video from PHAsset to upload it on Dropbox.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I has same problem

Comment: Got solution for this. I am stuck at the same point